# AngularJS - Generate a pdf from a byte array in ie9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, nancy

Is it possible to generate a pdf from a byte array in ie9 and open the pdf in a new window?  I'm currently using `Blob` which (of course) isn't supported in IE9.  I'm currently looking for an alternative method of doing this.  If this isn't possible, is there a way to at least prompt the user to open/save the file?  Here's my current code to open the pdf:

```
this.$http.get(this._apiBase + "/Disclosures/View/" + disclosureId, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).success((data) => {
    var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileUrl);
});
```